# How to display the latest values of database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tabel like this:

[image]

And I'm going to display the latest value of name and temperature, how can I do it?

I tried the SQL query:

```
SELECT name, temperature,MAX(Time) AS max_time   
FROM marker
WHERE Time = max_time   
;
```

But it has not given the desired result.

The desired result:

```
Sensor #1 8 2016-06-05 01:00:00
Sensor #1 8 2016-06-05 01:00:00
Sensor #1 8 2016-06-05 01:00:00
Sensor #1 8 2016-06-05 01:00:00
Sensor #1 8 2016-06-05 01:00:00
```

**I decided it like this:**

```
SELECT name, temperature, Time
FROM marker
WHERE Time = (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM marker);
```

Comment: And what **is** the desired result?

Comment: I added the desired result. You can check it.

Comment: And now please explain the logic behind it.

Comment: @easy_peasy . . . The desired result does not make any sense.  Why would the same row be repeated five times?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, temperature, time
FROM marker m
WHERE timeval= (SELECT MAX(time) FROM marker p where p.name=m.name);
```

This should work. In your query since you do not have a `where` clause inside the subquery it tries to match the max time of all rows which is not intended I believe.

Comment: I have mistake: "max_time is unknown column".